# How to update cache in PWA (No Framework)

Tags: javascript, caching, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

Am working on PWA and am trying to make my App works offline, so i cache my assets and its works fine, i could even use my app through my cached assets, BUT the problem is whenever i delete my cache using dev tools or whenever i update something in my assets my app not regenerate the cache again, how to regenrate the cache everytime when i start using the app online

Service worker registeration (app.js):

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator){
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('./sw.js')
        .then((reg) => console.log('Service worker registered', reg))
        .catch((err) => console.log('Service worker not registered', err));
}
```

My service worker looks like this:

```
const cacheName = 'VSCode_SG_' + Date.now(),
      assets = [
        './',
        './app.min.js',
        './favicon.ico',
        './style.css',
      ];

self.addEventListener('install', evt => {
    evt.waitUntil(caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => {
        cache.addAll(assets);
    }))
});

self.addEventListener('activate', evt => {
    // Get all the currently active `Cache` instances.
    evt.waitUntil(caches.keys().then((keys) => {
      // Delete all caches that aren't in the allow list:
      return Promise.all(keys.map((key) => {
        if (!cacheName.includes(key)) {
          return caches.delete(key);
        }
      }));
    }));
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', evt => {
    evt.respondWith(
        caches.match(evt.request).then(cacheRes => {
            return cacheRes || fetch(evt.request);
        }).catch(() => console.log('An error has occurred'))
    );
});
```

am sure that am missing a small detail to solve the problem but i don't have any clues, anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue might be related to your caches name, you want it to stay a static name instead of labeling it with a date stamp

```
const cacheName = 'VSCode_SG_STATIC', // keep it a constant string
      assets = [
        './',
        './app.min.js',
        './favicon.ico',
        './style.css',
      ];
```

Give this a shot and wait until your new service worker is installed to try again